# Gnuplot cblabel not appearing

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot a function of two variables represented in tabular form. I would like to label my color bar while representing this as a heatmap. No matter how much I rescale, no luck, and I don't even see the colorbar label appearing. Here is my gnuplot script:

```
set title "Flux in core vs radius and height"
set view map
set cblabel "Neutron flux (cm^-2 s^-1)"
set xlabel "Radius (cm)"
set ylabel "Axial distance from center (cm)"
splot "flux.out" using 1:2:3 with image
```

And the result looks like this, lacking a colorbar label:

[image: Plot without colorbar]

Comment: I can not reproduce the picture without the data file and without knowing which output terminal you have used to produce the picture (just a screenshot on Linux/Windows?, png?, ...). But it seems that the `cblabel` is outside the picture. Can you try to set the left and right margins manually with `set lmargin at screen 0.1` and `set rmargin at screen 0.7` and playing with the numbers?

Comment: Hi @maij, this was an exported png from using the 'qt' terminal in gunplot on ubuntu 16.10. Your suggestion fixed the problem! Changing the margins was all that was needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cblabel` is printed outside the picture. You can manually adjust the margins to make some space for the label:

```
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.7
```

I used `at screen` because else the picture would be cropped again. And I also set `lmargin` because else in my test the ylabel would not fit on the page.

Tested with Gnuplot 4.6.